# wsl ubuntu debug stm32 with openocd in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, stm32, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openocd

When I call openocd which is linux executable , it give me :

```
./openocd  -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s /mnt/c/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/ODrive/Firmware  -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f7x.cfg -c "reset_config none separate"
xPack OpenOCD x86_64 Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev (2021-12-07-17:30)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : DEPRECATED target event trace-config; use TPIU events {pre,post}-{enable,disable}
none separate

Info : Listening on port 50001 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 50002 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
Error: open failed
```

Because of we cant call avalible usb device from WSL , so we call .exe in WSL for instead .

```
 /mnt/c/openocd/bin/openocd.exe -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s /mnt/c/Users/Administrator/Desktop/work/ODrive/Firmware  -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f7x.cfg -c "reset_config none separate"Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-00572-g94e7535be (2022-02-19-14:36)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD  
Info : DEPRECATED target event trace-config; use TPIU events {pre,post}-{enable,disable}
none separate

Info : Listening on port 50001 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 50002 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 2000 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J29M18 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:374B
Info : Target voltage: 3.224258
Info : stm32f7x.cpu: Cortex-M7 r1p1 processor detected
Info : stm32f7x.cpu: target has 8 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32f7x.cpu on 50000
Info : Listening on port 50000 for gdb connections
```

then we successfully detect stm device in WSL

But when I start from VSCode . with

```
  {
            // For the Cortex-Debug extension
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "servertype": "openocd",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug ODrive v4.x - ST-Link",
            "executable": "${workspaceRoot}/build/ODriveFirmware.elf",
            "configFiles": [
                "interface/stlink.cfg",
                "target/stm32f7x.cfg",
            ],
            
            "showDevDebugOutput": "both",
            "openOCDLaunchCommands": [
                "reset_config none separate"
            ],
            "svdFile": "${workspaceRoot}/Private/v4/STM32F722.svd",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
```

The command automatically add

```
-f /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.2.2/support/openocd-helpers.tcl
```

which cause

```
pen On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-00572-g94e7535be (2022-02-19-14:36)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
embedded:startup.tcl:26: Error: Can't find /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.2.2/support/openocd-helpers.tcl
in procedure 'script' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 26
```

Then I do an test whihc delete file locate in Windows openocd\share\openocd\scripts
I find when execute openocd.exe in WSL it will search path whihc on Windows instead of ubuntu file . which means it can't find /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.2.2/support/openocd-helpers.tcl the isn't exsit on Window But on WSL .

My question why vscode server insert that file and how I Solve problem like this?

Comment: There is already an open issue regarding WSL2 support on cortex-debug GitHub: https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/issues/467

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar; I don't know if these changes will help you.  The Cortex Debugger was updated in Feb 2022 and in order for me to continue to use it, I added this line to .vscode/launch.json for all my launch specifications:

`"searchDir": ["/mnt/c/openocd/tcl", "//wsl$/Ubuntu-18.04"]`

You can find other debug attributes in https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/blob/master/debug_attributes.md. The addition `"//wsl$/Ubuntu-18.04"` to the searchDir allowed GDB to find the cortex settings in my ubuntu home path (~/.vscode-server/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.2.2). I don't know if you need `"/mnt/c/openocd/tcl"`, but you would need to include other paths your setup previously used.

Other changes you may want to consider are

1. Change "runToMain": true, to "runToEntryPoint": "main": Cortex Debugger has deprecated runToMain.
2. Change ${workspaceRoot} to ${workspaceFolder} : this is not a Cortex-debugger deprecation, rather a VSCode deprecation.